# Cell text overlaps the editingAccessory when try to delete a row in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, overlap

When I compile my app in the new iOS7, I found a problem when entering in the edit mode of an UITableView.

When I press in the red minus button to delete a row of the table, this row indent to the left to let appear the 'Delete' button. However, when this button appears, the text of the cell overlaps the editingAccesory (this happens only when the text is longer than the length of the cell).

How can I remove the overlapping?

**Edit:** Images in the comments

**Edit 2:** Tis is the code of the creation of the table

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{  
        return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
        return [_tweetList count];
} 

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SessionDetailCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        Tweet *tweet = [_tweetList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = tweet.text;
        return cell;
 }

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
                [tableView beginUpdates];

                Tweet *deletedTweet = [_tweetList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                [_selectedSession removeTweetsObject:deletedTweet];
                [deletedTweet deleteEntity];
                _tweetList = [Tweet findAllSortedBy:@"index" ascending:YES withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"session == %@",_selectedSession]];
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

                [tableView endUpdates];
        }
        [[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext]saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:nil];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        selectedPath = indexPath;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"EditTweet" sender:self];
}
```

**Solution:**

Finally, I put the accessoryButton in the default state, and I use the edit state only to delete the rows. It's the only solution I've found :(

Perhaps, the method "willTransitionToState" can help people to solve similar problems.

Comment: **Images:**

This image is before press the red minus button

![before](http://imageshack.com/a/img692/6899/1n29.png)

This image is when I press the red minus button

![when I press](http://imageshack.com/a/img819/7026/3kwp.png)

This image is after I press the red minus button, but don't deleting the row

![after](http://imageshack.com/a/img812/1723/no8y.png)

Comment: the result is the same :( and no, it's a normal cell, I don't custom it

Comment: Past some code of create cell in question It may help other to understand your problem, and i am deleting my all comment as it is not useful.

Comment: Code added, I hope this help people to help me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide or remove **editingAccesory** in editing mode , so there is no overlapping there,

set this,
[image]

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I need the editingAccessory: when I enter in the edit mode, I can delete the row, or edit it (this leads to another screen). Thank you anyway =)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question, because in iOS 8.3 I faced the same problem, that it seems not possible to correctly display the editing accessory AND the delete confirmation without the cell content and the accessory item to overlap. Solving this issue without breaking the transition-animations was quite a challenge. ;)

So here is my solution (assuming that you are using autolayout constraints in IB):

1. Create a `UITableViewCell` subclass and link it to your table view cell in IB.
2. Add an outlet from the autolayout constraint specifying the horizontal spacing bewteen the right-most view and the cell's content view (trailing to margin).
3. Override `willTransitionToState` and `layoutSubviews` as shown below.

Table cell subclass:

```
@IBOutlet weak var horizontalSpaceConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func willTransitionToState(state: UITableViewCellStateMask) {
    if (state & UITableViewCellStateMask.ShowingDeleteConfirmationMask == UITableViewCellStateMask.ShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) {
        self.horizontalSpaceConstraint.constant = 49.0; // ugly, delete-confirmation width
    }
    super.willTransitionToState(state)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    if (!self.showingDeleteConfirmation) {
        self.horizontalSpaceConstraint.constant = 0.0;
    }
    super.layoutSubviews()
}
```

The reason why I cannot use `didTransitionToState()` (and use `layoutSubviews`instead) to reset the layout constraint is, that this function is simply not invoked (as of iOS 8.3) after transitioning from the delete-confirmation-state. It seems Apple did only handle the case, that the user actually deletes the row, but not the case that the delete-confirmation is closed without deleting the row. :(